# Why does Springer need 85,000 words in a monograph?

Tags: publications, books, publishers, publishability, monograph

I'm dealing with Springer about a monograph proposal. My draft was 80,000 words and they asked me to make it 85–100,000 words. I don't want to bother the editor with a question that is just out of curiosity. But, why do they need to expand it? What difference are 5,000 words going to make?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is probably an economic decision based on the balancing of input effort/cost and likely return on investment. But you *should* ask the editor to see whether it is a "hard" rule or not and if you ask that, then you might as well ask why. I don't know if they make exceptions.

An exception might be "above the pay grade" of an individual editor, or not.

Comment: A lot of the economic issues come from the cost of binding.  At 85,000 words this will be about half cover, half pages, by thickness.  I think Springer monographs still have printed and bound editions.

Comment: @TerryLoring, if a volume is too thin it limits what can be put on the spine. That seems like a dumb reason but might figure in.

Comment: 80k words is definitely not in the "too thin" regime.

Comment: It's also highly unlikely that this is a purely economic issue (in the sense of how much it takes to produce a book). The biggest factors that change the cost of that are 1) page size, do you use 9x6 pages for example and 2) total page count (longer books are more expensive).

Comment: @Allure, I don't have any examples on my shelf, but outfits like Springer may like their logo on the spine and they might like it nicely sized. This is a corporate choice. I've had issues with books of under 200 pages and don't have many constraints about what need to appear there. I like my name to appear, of course, but don't insist on the bulldog. ;-)

Comment: Hard to believe.  My experience (as an individual purchaser of Springer-published documents) is that Springer picks a random number north of $100 and uses that.  Then either subtracts $2 or adds (!!) $2 for the ebook - which is what really annoys me.

Comment: @davidbak: economic issue in the sense of "if the book is too thin, our margin is too small and our shareholders are unhappy" rather than "if the book is too thin, we lose money".

Comment: @Taladris - I get that in general, but for Springer in particular, their pricing is whatever the captive suckers - I mean, market - will bear.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an educated guess based on my experience with other publishers. They ran an analysis to see which of their monographs are most profitable (or receive the most citations, or whatever other metric they care about). It turns out that there is a correlation between length and profit. Therefore they ask for a certain number of words.

It's almost surely not a hard requirement, they'll probably accept an 80k-word monograph if you adamantly refuse to lengthen the manuscript.

Comment: That would make sense. It’s said that there’s a “sweet spot” (word count) for every genre.

Comment: Goodhart's Law comes to mind: "If a measure becomes a target, it ceases to be a good measure" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodhart%27s_law

Comment: Can you share more about "your experience with other publishers"? In which part of the process did you participate?

Comment: @Taladris I currently work in academic publishing, and I had an insider's view as to why there is a guideline for X number of words for journal articles.

Comment: If you mean "experience working for other publishers" please say that.  "experience with" is ambiguous as to the relationship that led to the experience.